# Jdbc Template and MySql interaction for Frequently Changing Queries

Tags: java, mysql, domain-driven-design, jdbctemplate

There are some queries used by a DAO layer that is implemented in JDBC Template

```
String longQuery = ".....";
public List<AnObject> findObjectsBySomething(Something s) {
    return getJdbcTemplate().queryForObjects(longQuery, myRowMapper, s);
}
```

longQuery is going to frequently change, but I don't want to have to manage it right in the source code.  How do you go about handling this?  I need jdbc template source code, and at least the basics of setting it up in mysql.

Other requirements:

- Cannot be a View, I already tried this and my query is too complicated (derived tables)
- Needs to query across other mysql databases on the same server
- Needs to return a list of Ids, which could many, several thousand possibly

Comment: I'm not sure what's the question...how to store those queries?

Comment: I don't want the query stored in the java file, and honestly, I'd prefer it to be in the database, not in a text file or anything like that, but I'm not sure what to do

Answer (score 0):

How different is this query? You can store them as files(DAO_NNN.sql where NNN is an id to a specific SQL statement) or store them in an XML file.

Comment: I'd really prefer having it stored in the database, something more along the lines of a stored procedure

Comment: you want keep in db SQL statements to access the db :) not a very good idea I would say :)

Comment: I still don't have a big picture... can you give me an examples?

Comment: My application uses a query that may need to change in the future, I don't want it stored in the application code AT ALL, I don't want the SQL in a string, I don't want it in a text file, I don't want it stored in any way that is not managed by the database.  I'm not saying I want to store it in a table in the database, I want it stored in a function/view/stored procedure that way the code references it by name and I can change it on the fly later in the DB